# Ultrasonic and infrared sensor availability?

Tags: ros2, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there one for ros2 foxy and igniton citadel?

I can only find lidar on citadel, but I'm having hard time to find ones for ultrasonic and IR sensor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27353/ultrasonic-and-infrared-sensor-availability?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2021-09-15**:
I am not aware of an implementation of ultrasonic or IR sensor, however both can be approximated by using lidar with several layers, I've done it recently for US sensor.

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-09-17**:
Thanks for your reply! Sorry, I'm not sure how I wasn't notified by this. I got my answers already. I will post the answer for citadel or any ign versions

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2021-10-15**:
No problem, I'm glad you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the way to insert them inside Citadel.
Since there is no official plugin for ultrasonic or infrared sensor. I will be more than happy to share on here for anyone in future!

**Ultrasonic:**
This is being used as in lidar. It is included the setting of ultrasonic. Here is what I wrote:

```
  <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <topic>ultrasonic</topic>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <lidar>
          <scan>
              <vertical>
                <samples>5</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>0.00</min_angle>
                <max_angle>0.25</max_angle>
              </vertical>
          </scan>
      <range>
        <min>0.120000</min>
        <max>4</max>
        <resolution>0.015000</resolution>
      </range>
      <noise>
        <type>gaussian</type>
        <mean>0.0</mean>
        <stddev>0.01</stddev>
      </noise>
    </lidar>
```

Which this will results as one "cone" acting like ultrasonic.

Use sensor_msgs/msg/range to get the range in ros2 foxy (i don't know about ros1 since I joined ros2 only)

**Infrared sensor:**
This is one of the most fun challenge ever I had!
Since there is no official plugin for infrared sensor, I used the alternative plugin called Depth camera which is display on [github](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/tree/foxy/ros_ign_gazebo_demos)

Since depth camera code in sdf is a little too long. Here is the code in github! It's open source as well! Feel free to explore as well since there will be a lot of documents involves Foxy (ros2) and Citadel (LTS atm)

I'm going to mark this as my official answer since it solved my issue.

[image: image description]

Feel free to message me with questions if you have even if you are in 2023 or 2026 :P

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2021-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-09-17**:
I just wanted to mention this, I use citadel with ros2 only.